# MAC Bootcamp Windows 8 :Visual Studio 2012 Crashes when Trying to run Simulator of Windows App

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2012, simulator, windows, bootcamp

I am currently running bootcamp on mac, windows 8, visual studio 2012. Whenever I run the app simulator it crashes. What is the problem, and how would I fix this?

Here is the screenshot of the crash. And it crashes right when I hit run button.
[image]